# Index error when running a for loop based on len of a list

Tags: python, json

I'm working with a large json file with an object that has over 300 nodes. I'd like to compile these nodes in a list for later use.

I've written the below code to accomplish this but am having trouble with for loop at the end

```
import json

a = open('file.json')
data = a.read()
j = json.loads(data)
l = len(j['field']['items']) 

q = []
for i in range(l):
    m = j['field']['items'][i]['values'][0]['value']
    q.append(m)
```

From my understanding, i here represents the node number under the field object and it is pulling from the variable l (which is the number of nodes under the object).

I've tested by manually inputing numbers for i (0, 1, 2...358) and it works, but when I run the above loop, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, given that `l = len(j['field']['items'])` and that the `i` values come from `range(l)`, it follows that `j['field']['items'][i]` should be in bounds. However, there is another place on that line of code where an attempt is made to index into a list. Do you see it? Do you understand why it might fail?

Comment: Separately: while you *can* loop this way, it would be *much easier* to assign `j['field']['items']` to a variable, and then loop `for` each of the *elements in that list*. Using `range` to make indices, and then indexing in with them, is going out of your way to complicate the code. Make sure you understand that `range` is *just a function* that has *nothing to do with* the `for` loop syntax; and make sure you understand how Python's `for` loops work.

Comment: Also: instead of reading the file yourself into a string, and then using `.loads` on the string, just use `.load` on the file. That's why there are separate functions provided in the `json` module. It would also be a good idea to learn about `with` blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Are you referring to the last [0]? This is intentional. Using a JSON explorer, I'm showing my json has a node structure of: field -> items -> number -> value -> 0 -> Data that I'm after.

Comment: Yes. Did you try to check that the `[0]` element is actually there, in every case? An empty list would not contain one. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to diagnose the exact cause of the error. What data causes the error? Which subscript is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate directly over the items in a collection instead of using an index. In your case,

```
import json

j = json.load("file.json")
items = j['field']['items'] 

q = []
for item in items:
    m = item['values'][0]['value']
    q.append(m)
```

This avoids `list index out of range` errors when trying to iterate using `range(len(collection))`.

Comment: Though true (and certainly preferable), this does not address the error described (or at least I can't see why it would).

Comment: Confirmed this doesn't address the issue.

Comment: With this approach, though, you should find it much easier to understand the problem. For example, try to check the value of `item` at the beginning of each loop.

Comment: @redwytnblakII without an example of the JSON in question, there isn't much more I can suggest. I would do what Karl suggested and make sure all your indexing is correct. Using an interactive REPL with the data is very useful.